# When I use a function that I append to the class Controller, it does not work in Yii

Tags: yii

I appended a xxx function to the class Controller, then I touched a file named 'VideoController'.  It's extends Controller.

When I execute the VideoController, the xxx function can't be called, why?

the function ajaxReturn :

```
class Controller extends CController
{
    /**
     * @var string the default layout for the controller view. Defaults to '//layouts/column1',
     * meaning using a single column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column1.php'.
     */
    public $layout='//layouts/column1';
    /**
     * @var array context menu items. This property will be assigned to {@link CMenu::items}.
     */
    public $menu=array();
    /**
     * @var array the breadcrumbs of the current page. The value of this property will
     * be assigned to {@link CBreadcrumbs::links}. Please refer to {@link CBreadcrumbs::links}
     * for more details on how to specify this property.
     */
    public $breadcrumbs=array();

    /**
     * zhoumengkang
     * 从Thinkphp里拖过来的
     */
    protected function ajaxReturn($data,$info='',$status=1,$type='JSON') {
        $result  =  array();
        $result['status']  =  $status;
        $result['info'] =  $info;
        $result['data'] = $data;
        if(strtoupper($type)=='JSON') {
            header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8");
            exit(json_encode($result));
        }elseif(strtoupper($type)=='XML'){
            header("Content-Type:text/xml; charset=utf-8");
            exit(xml_encode($result));
        }elseif(strtoupper($type)=='EVAL'){
            header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8");
            exit($data);
        }else{
            // TODO
        }
    }
}
```

but it can't by called in

```
class VideoController extends Controller {
    public function actionTest() {
            $this->ajaxReturn(true,'test',1);
    }
}
```

Comment: is that function public / protected?

Comment: add your XXX function and videocontroller code.

Comment: show your code please

Comment: are you sure you have created controller class which have ajaxReturn()?

Comment: @kumar_v  be shy ，i am a freshman , so it takes a long time to edit it.

Comment: Be sure you have imported Controller.php or kept on Components folder. Be sure Controller.php has Controller class inside with above function. Be sure you have extended Contoller class properly. I have tested your code and its working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import your controller before extend.

```
    Yii::import('application.controllers.Controller');
    class VideoController extends Controller {
    public function actionTest() {
            $this->ajaxReturn(true,'test',1);
    }
}
```

Better change your controller name from `Controller` to `someothername`.

Comment: the VideoController is in the dir (myapp/protected/modules/admin/controller) if i need use the function ajaxReturn(),could you  recommend a class file to add this function. because i have try to add to many place (such as CController) ,whatever where it‘s added ,it  always dosen't work.3Q!

Comment: the ajaxReturn will be used everywhere in my app ,so where is the best place it should be  placed ?

Comment: Then you should do ajaxReturn() in some common place like general/functions.php. Then include this functions.php in your index.php file. So, you can call this ajaxReturn() anywhere in the project.